# Creating plugin to call mybb header template in Smarty 3

Tags: php, smarty

I am working with a Smarty 3 script and I need to call mybb header and footer templates. I normally just create a .php page and put the eval code directly in it but I can't do that with smarty I have to make a plugin. Is it possible to make a plugin that calls templates from mybb?

The normal code to call mybb templates would be like..

```
<?php 

define('IN_MYBB', 1); require "./global.php";

add_breadcrumb("Title here", "somename.php"); 

eval("\$html = \"".$templates->get("template_name")."\";"); 

output_page($html);

?>
```

I have never worked with Smarty let alone making plugins for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign anything to variable in PHP using Smarty, you could use `fetch()` method.

For example in PHP:

```
$html = $smarty->fetch('template.tpl');
```

In Smarty template file:

```
This is template.
```

And after running it, you will have assigned `This is template` text to `$html` variable.

Comment: I need it pulled from a template within MyBB. so it can't be in a .tpl

Comment: @Jakeman22 I don't understand. So why you use Smarty when you don't want to use templates? What's the point? At the moment your question is completely unclear. I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am using it because I am using a pastebin script made with it. templates that I am trying to use are stored in mybb. It is retrieved using the code posted in the first post. If I put that in a php file and opened it. I would get the template. I would normally just use include_once('header.php') and be done. but I can't do that with smarty.